# force download after QR scan

Tags: php, html, qr-code

I have a question. I am using a QR code to download a music. 
The QR code has a link on the format: http://example.com/musics/track.mp3

If the QR code is scan with for example Kaywa Reader, the music is directly downloaded to the phone. However, if the QR code is scan with QR Code Reader, the QR code reader shows me the URL (http://example.com/musics/track.mp3) and if I select "Browse website" the music is played in streaming through the web navigator, but instead I want to have the music downloaded to the phone.

When I am searching on internet, I see 2 kind of reply: 
- changing the MIME type of the file to application/octet
- to add an anchor as `<a href="http://example.com/musics/track.mp3" download></a>`

Is there any others possibility to force a download from a url (like if the user tap the URL directly, without click on a link).

Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with specifying the desired behavior via the appropriate response header?

Comment: _"Is there any others possibility to force a download from a url (like if the user tap the URL directly, without click on a link)."_ - without a link, the URL is just "text". How the application wants to handle the user clicking on text, is of course up to the application - the QR reader application, and therefor largely out of your control.

Comment: The question I got was: "the musics need to be downloaded directly after scanning the QR code" (so to force the end-user to download the music on their devise).

The method with .htaccess works fine.

Comment: _"The method with .htaccess works fine"_ - that basically is the MIME type method, which you said you knew about already, and you asked for _other_ ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `htaccess` to achieve this functionality like following:

```
<Files *.mp3>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

It will force the `*.mp3` files inside the `musics` folder to download. Obviously you can use `*.*` to force download all files inside that directory. Put this code in `.htaccess` in the `musics` directory.

And if you are using `Apache` and have access to *Apache's Config*, you can add the following inside `httpd.conf`:

```
<Location "/musics/">
    <Files *.mp3>
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </Files>
</Location>
```